# How to stop consuming messages with @RabbitListener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

When I use MessageListenerAdapter to handle message, I could call SimpleMessageListenerContainer.stop() to stop consume from the queue. But after I change to use @RabbitListener to listen, I can't find a method like this. I tried CachingConnectionFactory.stop() but doesn't work. Could anyone help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

1. Give the `@RabbitListener` an `id`.
2. Get a reference to the [listener endpoint registry bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#_container_management) by autowiring etc.
3. Calling `stop()` on the registry will stop all containers.
4. Call `getListenerContainer(id).stop()` to stop an individual container.

Comment: @Garry What if we want to gracefully stop consuming messages? Please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991826/how-to-gracefully-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener