# Spring-Boot/AMQP - Limit number of messages processed

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a spring-boot application using the spring-boot AMQP library.

*pom.xml* :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

How can I make it process and acknowledge a **single** message then gracefully exit ?

Can make it exit without acknowledge but cannot seem to work out how to acknowledge the message then exit !

Comment: So, you want to ack and process only one message? What if the queue has 100 messages?

Comment: @DarshanMehta Yes i want to process a single message and exit even if the queue has 100 messages.

Comment: you can use similar approach as this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035454/how-to-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener. Maybe add an `AtomicInteger` and stop consuming once the count reaches 1? As far as the ack is concerned, Spring will only send an ack if your `listener` method exits gracefully. If you call `stop()`, it won't ack and hence, the message will be available for other users to consume.

Comment: @DarshanMehta perhaps i could increment the count at the end of processing the first message and then exit at the start of processing the second should the count reach my specified limit (of 1 in my case)

Comment: Exactly, `incrementAndGet()` is the method you would like to use with `AtomicInteger` and yes, incrementing the count in the end of the method and checking in the beginning is a good idea. I would use `@Value` to configure the number of messages the app needs to read before exiting.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Thanks - stick that in an answer and i will mark it as accepted

Comment: I think it would be easier to use the `RabbitTemplate` instead.

Comment: @ManseUK done..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use one of the `RabbitTemplate.receive()` (or `receiveAndConvert()`) methods instead of using a listener container.

Comment: So this would consumer a message based on request rather then listen for messages - nice idea

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below steps:

- Use Spring's `RabbitListener` as listener (Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035454/how-to-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener) for the complete example)
- Declare an `AtomicInteger` as counter in your listener class
- Increment the counter once you listen to the message (i.e. `listen` method executes without any Exception). Spring will only send an ack when the method executes successfully
- If the value of counter is more than `0` (or more than the configured threshold), stop listening by calling `stop()` method
- Use `@Value` to configure the threshold and use `incrementAndget()` method to atomically increment the counter