# How to gracefully stop consuming messages with @RabbitListener

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is there a way to gracefully stop a `ListenerContainer`, and its associated `Consumers`.

**What I'm trying to achieve.**

1. Stop consuming messages.
2. Gracefully stop `ListenerContainer`.
3. Await long running consumers, and ack when finished.

I'm able to stop the `ListenerContainers` using `consumer.stop()`, but active long running consumers won't complete successfully, and processed messages won't be acked and will therefore be processed again, once the ListenerContainer has been resumed.

**Output**

```
Waiting for workers to finish.
Workers not finished.
Closing channel for unresponsive consumer: Consumer@6d229b1c
```

The message was processed, but not acked.

I might be able to achieve a graceful shutdown using `setForceCloseChannel(false)`, but is it possible to verify if the cancelled consumers has finished? SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doShutDown() has a local scoped List "canceledConsumers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the shutdown timeout.

See [Message Listener Container Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#containerAttributes).

> **shutdownTimeout**

> When a container shuts down (for example, if its enclosing ApplicationContext is closed), it waits for in-flight messages to be processed up to this limit. Defaults to five seconds.

```
/**
 * The time to wait for workers in milliseconds after the container is stopped. If any
 * workers are active when the shutdown signal comes they will be allowed to finish
 * processing as long as they can finish within this timeout. Defaults
 * to 5 seconds.
 * @param shutdownTimeout the shutdown timeout to set
 */
public void setShutdownTimeout(long shutdownTimeout) {
```

**EDIT**

There is now a new property `forceStop` to stop the container after the current message is processed, requeueing other prefetched messages. https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#forceStop

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Even with setShutdownTimeout,  the last consumed message might not be acked. I believe the best option is to use setForceCloseChannel(false), but then I cannot determine if the canceled consumers has finished or not.

I might have to extend the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory, and re-implement/extend the SimpleMessageListenerContainer to get hold of the canceledConsumers.

Comment: `>Even with setShutdownTimeout, the last consumed message might not be acked` Why do you say that? Make the timeout a large value; `stop()` will block until the last consumer thread completes. You can add an `ApplicationListener<AsyncConsumerStoppedEvent>` (or an `@EventListener`method) to get an event as each consumer thread exits). See [Consumer Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#consumer-events). You can also set the force close to false as extra protection if you want.

Comment: No matter how high we set `setShutdownTimeout`, the consumer will continue to process newly arrived messages, until the timeout has been reached.

So, if the consumer start processing a message just before the timeout has been reached, the message won't be acked.

I can put together an example on github.

Comment: No it will not; `doShutdown()` cancels the consumer so no more messages will arrive for it. Furthermore, the consumer runs in a loop `while(isActive()...` and `shutDown()` sets `active` to false before calling `doShutDown()`.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake. The "issue" might only occur if the `setShutdownTimeout` is less than the initial `numberOfMessages` * `consumerExecutionTimePerMessage`. I'm fine with that. Thanks.

Comment: There is now a new property `forceStop` to stop the container after the current message is processed, requeueing other prefetched messages. https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#forceStop

Answer (score 1):

To complete @user634545's last comment, we have to deal with 2 properties :

- [shutdownTimeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#shutdownTimeout)
- [prefetchCount](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#prefetchCount)

These parameters must be ajusted in order to validate the following :

```
prefetchCount < (shutdownTimeout / consumerExecutionTimePerMessage)
```

It would mean that after receiving the shutdown order, the consumer should be able to consume and aknowledge every prefetched messages.

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be `prefetchCount < (shutdownTimeout / consumerExecutionTimePerMessage)`?

Comment: Absolutely, you're rigtht, I edit the formula.

Comment: There is now a new property `forceStop` to stop the container after the current message is processed, requeueing other prefetched messages. https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#forceStop