# @RabbitListener (having id set) not registered with RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-batch, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using `@RabbitListener` to consume a message from RabbitMQ. I want to have the ability to pause/resume the message consume process based on some a threshold.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035454/how-to-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991826/how-to-gracefully-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener) SO posts, I could be able to use `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` and get the list of containers and pause/resume consuming based on need. I also understand that to be able to register to RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry, I need to specify an **id** to `@RabbitListener` annotation.

However, I have add an id to `@RabbitListener` annotation and still `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()` **returns me a empty collection.**

I am not sure, what could be the issue due to which i could not get the ListenerContainers collection.

Here is now I create the `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`. ( I use `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` because I need to consume from different queues)

```
public static SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory getSimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter,
        final AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin,
        final String queueName, final String bindExchange,
        final String routingKey, final int minConsumerCount,
        final int maxConsumerCount, final int msgPrefetchCount,
        final AcknowledgeMode acknowledgeMode) {

    LOGGER.info("Creating SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory to consume from Queue '{}', " +
                    "using {} (min), {} (max) concurrent consumers, " +
                    "prefetch count set to {} and Ack mode is {}",
            queueName, minConsumerCount, maxConsumerCount, msgPrefetchCount, acknowledgeMode);

    /**
     * Before creating the connector factory, ensure that the model with appropriate
     * binding exists.
     */
    createQueueAndBind(amqpAdmin, bindExchange, queueName, routingKey);

    // Create listener factory
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();

    // set connection factory
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    // set converter
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter);

    // set false so that if model is missing the app will not crash
    factory.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);

    // set min concurrent consumer
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(minConsumerCount);

    // set max concurrent consumer
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConsumerCount);

    // how many message should be fetched in a go
    factory.setPrefetchCount(msgPrefetchCount);

    // set acknowledge mode to auto
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(acknowledgeMode);

    // captures the error on consumer side if any error
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());

    return factory;
}
```

@RabbitListener annotation declaration on a method

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${object.scan.queue-name}",
        id = "object-scan",
        containerFactory = "object.scan")
```

Comment: Could you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan - I am not experiencing any exception. However, I could not get the list of Listener Container when I call RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot or do you have an `@EnableRabbit`? Is your class with that `@RabbitListener` declared as a bean in the application context, e.g. via `@Bean` or `@Component` on the class per se?

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Its a Spring Boot app. I do have `@Component` annotation present in the class where the method is annotated with `@ RabbitListener`

Comment: Then it's time to share your project with us to us to play and reproduce an issue! It's not clear for now what is going on.Although it would be great to have a much info in the question as possible, so, we don't ask similar questions like mine any more...

Comment: I am trying to access the list before the app context is fully loaded. However, once after the context is fully up and running I am able to get the list of all `MessageListenerContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Before creating the connector factory, ensure that the model with appropriate
 * binding exists.
 */
createQueueAndBind(amqpAdmin, bindExchange, queueName, routingKey);
```

You should not be doing this during the bean definition phase; it's too early in the application context's lifecycle.

All you need to do is add the queue/exchange/binding `@Bean`s to the application context and Spring (RabbitAdmin) will automatically do the declarations when the container is first started.