# How to programmatically stop RabbitListener in Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rabbitmq

I have a RabbitListener that looks like:

```
@RabbitListener
public class ProductListener {

    @Queue(value = "product", executor = "product-listener") 
    public void receive(MyType message) {
        // process message
    }
}
```

In certain cases, I want to shut down my application. However, before doing so I would like to stop the RabbitListner from consuming new messages and give it some time to finish the processing of already received messages.

In spring this should be possible via `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry#getListenerContainer(String)` according to [How to stop consuming messages with @RabbitListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035454/how-to-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener) and [How to gracefully stop consuming messages with @RabbitListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991826/how-to-gracefully-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener) .
I didn’t find something similar for Micronaut. Is this possible with Micronaut?

Comment: You could try to set a value to the `rabbitmq.shutdown-timeout` in `SingleRabbitConnectionFactoryConfig` and it should stop consuming after the amout of time you provide

Comment: Do you mean I should call `SingleRabbitConnectionFactoryConfig.setShutdownTimeout(X)` ?  That should be set to 10 seconds by default.

Comment: And this default value isn't working for you ?