# How to pause @RabbitListener without destroying AnonymousQueue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a Spring Boot application that is generally message driven but on special occasions, the incoming messages need to be stopped. However I cannot loose those messages, I need to buffer them and receive them in the correct order later.

There are myriads of questions asked and answered about stopping the Listener via the ListernerEndpointRegistry, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035454/how-to-stop-consuming-messages-with-rabbitlistener?rq=1).

However when I stop the container the AnonymousQueue seems to disappear. I want the queue to stay on the exchange and buffer any messages, and receive them, when I restart. Is this possible or do I need to buffer them inside my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Don't use an anonymous (auto-delete) queue and use stop/start.
2. Don't stop the container; simply block the listener thread(s) when you want to suspend message delivery and wake them when you want to restart.

> However I cannot lose those messages

If you cannot lose messages, you should NEVER use an auto-delete queue - you can lose messages at any time if you have a simple network glitch.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have the thread wait then. Also big thanks for your note about the auto-delete queue. That sounds like an important point, I hadn't yet considered and I will probably move towards a statically declared queue after thinking through my requirements again.